# Passing dynamic value to http.post url using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch, angular-ui-router

I am fetching elasticsearch data including index, id, type, etc like below

```
$http.post('http://localhost:9200/abc/_search', searchCriteria).
                          then(function (response) {
                              $scope.responseData = response;
                          }, function (response) {
                          });
```

After fetching the response I am trying to pass the information in another URL to update the information in elasticsearch like below,

```
$http.post('http://localhost:9200/$scope.responseData._index/$scope.responseData._type/$scope.responseData._id/_update',postData).
```

I am newbie to Angularjs. I am not sure whether this will work or not. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would verify if your data are defined like that:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:9200/';
var index = $scope.responseData._index || null;
var type = $scope.responseDate._type || null;
var id = $scope.responseData._id || null;

if(index && type && id){
   url = url + index + '/' + type + '/' + id + '/_update';
   $http.post(url, postData);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply build the url string and then call the http post:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:9200/' + $scope.responseData._index + '/' + $scope.responseData._type + '/' + $scope.responseData._id + '/_update';
$http.post(url, postData);
```